# test coverage for rescue blocks in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, test-coverage, rescue

I am trying to get coverage on the following sections of code (from **begin** to **end**)in my attached spec where

```
def process_request(data)
    agents = agent_emails(data)
    begin
        ej = EmailerJob.new(agents: agents, data: data)
        CommonLogger.input_log(log_obj,"Sending Lead email to #{agents}")
        ej.deliver_emails
        rescue Timeout::Error => error
            CommonLogger.input_log(log_obj,"#{error}","error")
            raise error
        rescue StandardError => error
            Rails.logger.error "StandardError Handling for #{agents}"
            CommonLogger.input_log(log_obj,"#{error}","error")
        rescue Exception => error
            Rails.logger.error "Exception Handling for #{agents}"
            CommonLogger.input_log(log_obj,"#{error}","error")
            raise error
    end
end
```

coverage report:
[image]

Can somebody please help me how can i cover all rescue sections?

Rspec: 3.12.0

Comment: Why do you think this code should be rescuing those incredibly low level exceptions? Only rescue the exceptions that you actually know what to do with.

Comment: You could stub `ej.deliver_emails` and force those errors e.g. `ej = double; allow(EmailerJob).to receive(:new).and_return(ej); allow(ej).to receive(:deliver_emails).and_raise(Timeout::Error)` then test from there. [RSpec Mocks raising an error](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/raising-an-error).

Comment: If I answered this, I'd copy @engineersmnky's comment :) PS: I think it's OK to rescue "low-level" errors for the sake of logging, but I don't recommend ever rescuing `Exception`. Style guide: https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#no-blind-rescues